# Removing items based on values where an item can have multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a system that lists an number of items from a database, these items can have three different states that can be attached to it, Manual, Auto and VIP. A single item in this list could be either of this states and sometimes two or all three at the same time.

The system also has three filters, Manual, Auto and VIP.

I am trying to build a system so that when a state has changed on a filter (box is checked/unchecked) the system will hide or show items from this list.

So i am struggling with this concept with my current implementation.

here is some code:

```
<ul class="content-list" id="update-list">
<li class="list-item" 
    data-auto="1" 
    data-manual="1" 
    data-vip="1">

    <div class="list-avatar">
        <p class="multi-circle">A/M</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list-details">

        <h3 class="list-item-heading">Update #1  </h3><small class="list-timestamp">11/11/13</small>
        <div class="list-item-text">
        </div>
    </div>

</li>

<li class="list-item" 
    data-auto="1" 
    data-manual="1" 
    data-vip="0">

    <div class="list-avatar">
        <p class="multi-circle">A/M</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="list-details">

        <h3 class="list-item-heading">Update #2  </h3><small class="list-timestamp">11/11/13</small>
        <div class="list-item-text">
        </div>
    </div>

</li>

<li class="list-item" 
    data-auto="0" 
    data-manual="1" 
    data-vip="0">

    <div class="list-avatar">
        <p class="manual-circle">M</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list-details">

        <h3 class="list-item-heading">Update #3  </h3><small class="list-timestamp">11/11/13</small>
        <div class="list-item-text">
        </div>
    </div>

</li>
```

I have three "data-" attributes attached to each list item, i wanted to use these to detect if the item show be displayed or not but i can't think of a simple way of doing this.

My other thought on the matter would be to add a class to each item saying if it is Manual, Auto or VIP for example

```
<li class="list-item manual auto vip">
```

I understand how to remove and display elements this way however it seems a little messy to me.

So what is the best way of achieving this using Jquery? I think i might be over engineering the whole thing.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

For example, when someone wants to see the "data-auto" items, you could do the following:

```
$("li[data-auto='1']").show();
```

Comment: Is this the best way of doing it though?

Comment: "Best" in what way? Efficiency, clarity, conciseness? One possible implementation is seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4qrg4co/), where every time a checkbox is pressed, it hides every record and loops through the checkboxes to see which should be shown.

Comment: I guess a bit of all other them... haha